# What is the `802.11n Mode` setting in wireless driver for?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-driver

My **Wireless-N 2230** network card supports the `b/g/n` radio types.
I read on some forums, that my card does not support dual band.

But in the "Advanced" tab of my wireless driver I can see a `802.11n Mode` which is enabled and another setting.

I can set my router to transmission mode `802.11n`.
I have separated my network into "MyNetwork_2GHZ" and "MyNetwork_5GHZ" to differentiate both.
But I can only see the "...2GHZ" network.

**Therefore the question**: What is the `802.11n Mode` setting in wireless driver for?

[image]

**Interface name: Wi-Fi**

> ```
> Driver                    : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230
> Vendor                    : Intel Corporation
> Provider                  : Intel
> Date                      : 30.04.2015
> Version                   : 15.18.0.1
> INF file                  : oem30.inf
> Type                      : Native Wi-Fi Driver
> Radio types supported     : 802.11b 802.11g 802.11n
> FIPS 140-2 mode supported : Yes
> 802.11w Management Frame Protection supported : Yes
> Hosted network supported  : Yes
> ```

**Router - Send settings:**

[image]

Comment: You are confusing WiFi standard with bands... 802.11a/b/g/n/ac are different wireless standards, 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz are different bands. Your WiFi adapter is only single band (2.4Ghz) and cannot talk in the 5Ghz band, this is not necessarily tied to the WiFi standard, your WiFI adapter just uses 802.11b/g/n in the 2.4Ghz frequency range (channels 1-11/14 depending on regulatory area).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dual-band Routers that are listed as 802.11ac, can be assumed to be fully backwards compatible with 802.11 a/b/g/n.

That card supports wireless-n **only** over 2.4ghz. to get the advertised speeds for that card you may have to use it in 40mhz channel width mode. Also Some models support aggregating upper and lower channels in the 2.4ghz wireless-N modes for increased speeds.

The mode setting in the driver is to enable/disable the cards ability to negotiate wireless-n speeds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I kind of miss the emphasys of the 40mhz width mode, which is what this question really is about, and by that, I mean explaining, that by default the channel width is only 20mhz. But given that otherwise this answer is correct, +1 from me. :)

Comment: 802.11ac does not operate in 2.4GHz - Please clarify your answer.

Comment: @pythonian are you confused at the definition of "backwards compatibility?" It's pretty clear.

Comment: Yes I am confused! 11AC is backwards compatible to 11N on the 5GHz band.  It is not backwards compatible to 11B/G in the 2.4GHz band.

Comment: @pythonian I made it very clear in the comments on your answer

Comment: @pythonian This answer was clear b/g/n all support 2.4 GHz it was 802.11a that only supports 5 GHz.  You are alone in your confusion

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - Thanks for editing your answer.  Now it makes sense.

Comment: @Ramhound - What are you talking about?  Please read the thread and see Tim's correction.

Comment: What thread?  The answer is clear..  it’s original revision was clear